# building an application to change the color of screen , clicking on the button in android

Tags: android

Hey team i am new to android 
and building an application in which there would be two buttons one for setting and the other for use mirror.  Now when i will click on use mirror button , the color of the screen should become silver ,so that any one can use it as a mirror......

so plz help me to solve the problem

thanks

Comment: I have a silver background and I can tell you: use black! You never have a better mirror image than on a black turned off screen.

Comment: how should i do that can u tell me about the codes.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Use a ImageView and two buttons and change the image of the ImageView depending your button presses. A scaled 1x1 pixel image in the color you like should be sufficient.

If you don't know how you can implement what I just said, you should start reading some basic tutorials. This is pretty basic stuff so work with some tutorials before writing your own application (even if it is so simple)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.....actually i am new to this technology...thats why this problem occurs to me but thanks really appreceating you suggestion....